# DynamoDBMapper: Non-set collections aren't supported when try to convert a list

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I just encountered a problem with DynamoDBMapper, I have a Data class as below:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "postDB")
public class PostData {

    private String content;
    private String timestamp;
    private int uid;
    private List<CommentData> comments;

    ...
    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public List<CommentData> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }
    public void setComments(List<CommentData> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }
}
```

However, there is an error when complication:

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: Non-set collections aren't supported:
```

Would someone help me figure this out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What version of AWS SDK are you using? The support for List(s) has only been added when DynamoDB introduced document model only a year ago.

Upgrade your AWS SDK to 1.9+ to have support for `List`